# Query to fetch multiple records from table in same row

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my database like this :

**porfolio**

```
id  | title  | content
----+--------+-------------------
1   |  hello | aksjdhaksd..
2   |  hi    | asdasd..
----+--------+-------------------
```

**portfolio_image**

```
id  | portfolio_id  | image
----+---------------+-------------------
1   |  1            | a.jpg
2   |  1            | b.jpg
3   |  2            | c.png
4   |  2            | d.png
----+---------------+-------------------
```

I want to fetch data so that i get all data from portfolio table and their respective images from second table in the same row :

I mean something like this :

```
id  | title | content       | image1 | image2
----+-------+---------------+--------+-------------
1   | hello | aksjdhaksd..  | a.jpg  | b.jpg
2   |  hi   | asdasd..      | c.png  | d.png
----+-------+---------------+------------------------------
```

Please help Me

Comment: But why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only two images per portfolio, then you can do:

```
select p.id, p.title, p.content,
       min(pi.image) as image1,
       (case when max(pi.image) <> min(pi.image) then max(pi.iamge) as image2
from portfolio p join
     portfolio_image pi
     on p.id = pi.portfolio_id
group by p.id, p.title, p.content;
```

If you have multiple images, the easiest approach is to put them into a single column, using `group_concat()`:

```
select p.id, p.title, p.content, group_concat(pi.image) as images
from portfolio p join
     portfolio_image pi
     on p.id = pi.portfolio_id
group by p.id, p.title, p.content;
```

If you have multiple images, don't know how many, *and* want each in a separate column.  Then you need a dynamic pivot.  I would suggest that you google "mysql dynamic pivot" to find some examples.